# How can I convert an XMM register of single-precision floats to integers?

Tags: c++, c, sse, intrinsics

I have a bunch of packed floats inside an XMM register (using SSE intrinsics):

```
__m128 xmm = _mm_set_ps(4.0f, 3.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f);
```

I'd like to convert all of these to integers in one go. I found an intrinsic, that does what I want (`_mm_cvtps_pi16()`), but it yields 4x16-bit *short* instead of full-blown *int*. An intrinsic called `_mm_cvtps_pi32()` yields *int*, but only for the two lower values in `xmm`. I can use it, extract the values, move things around and use it again, but is there a simpler way? Why wouldn't there be a straightforward 32bit packed float -> 32bit integer instruction? Surely both fit in the same space of an XMM register?

**EDIT:** Okay, I see now that `_mm_cvtps_pi32()` returns __m64 instead of __m128, which means it operates on a MMX-style MM... register. That would explain why it returns just two ints, but now I'm wondering:

- Will I have trouble when compiling for x64? Reportedly, __m64 isn't supported there...
- Why didn't they extend this instruction when SSE rolled out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/iscenter-new/mpc/altix/altixdata/opt/intel/vtune/doc/users_guide/mergedProjects/analyzer_ec/mergedProjects/reference_olh/mergedProjects/instructions/instruct32_hh/vc54.htm) documentation: `__m128d _mm_cvtps_epi32(__m128d a)` generates a `cvtps2dq` instruction, which does what you want.

Comment: It's worth taking a moment to understand the suffixes.  In this case the question's `pi32` leads directly to this answer's `epi32` -- the `e` for extended.  Extended, parallel, integer of 32 bits.

Comment: I used to think `__m128d` was used for storing two 64-bit floats, that's why I didn't look at this intrinsic more carefully. Any idea why this return type?

Comment: Okay, it looks as we were both wrong, the return type is actually `__m128i` and all is right now. The intrinsic is documented in the `__m128d` section of the SSE2 docs on MSDN, though, for a reason I don't understand.

Comment: I can't vouch for the documentation (I didn't write it, I just searched for the instruction I wanted), but it seems like the other answer also suggests `_mm_cvtps_epi32`, so it may be worth trying that one.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's just that I find these docs very confusing. Accepting now.

Comment: Yeah, I look up the instruction in my books first, then search for it with google...

Comment: It looks like there are mistakes on the page you link to - the intrinsic should be: `__m128i _mm_cvtps_epi32 (__m128 a)` - I recommend using the [Intel Intrinsics Guide](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-intrinsics-guide) for looking this stuff up, rather than Google or Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Use documentation (_mm_cvtps_epi32):

[Magic documentation.](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_sse2_int_conversion.htm)

Comment: I guess it's my bad for sticking with the MSDN docs. I figured it was the way to go, since I'm writing in Visual C++ on Windows.

Comment: Some times you need to search deeper: [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdc42k5e(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: A more useful reference is the [Intel Intrinsics Guide](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-intrinsics-guide) - it's a documentation tool for Linux/Windows/OS X and it's much more comprehensive/accurate and quicker/easier to use than MSDN.