# convertion of four packed single precision floating point to unsigned double words in x86-SSE

Tags: assembly, x86-64, sse, floating-point-conversion, sse3

Is there a way to convert four packed single precision floating point values to four double words in x86 with SSE extension?
The closest instruction would be **CVTPS2PI**, but it cannot be executed on two xmm registers, instead should be given as `CVTPS2PI MM, XMM/M64`. What if I want something like `<conversion_mnemonic> XMM, XMM/M128`?

Thanks.
Iman.

Comment: Are the results supposed to be of integer type?

Comment: Perhaps try `cvtps2dq`?

Comment: thanks @fuz. cvtps2dq will do the job apprently, but to four packed signed doubleword. Are you aware of a similar instruction for the unsigned double word type?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is such an instruction.

Comment: If you want unsigned integers, you should specify that in your question. Also, what rounding and overflow behavior do you want?

Comment: Thanks @chtz. Rounding: round to the nearest integer. Overflow: actually I'm not working with large floating points and they are all positive, so doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x86 doesn't have native support for FP<->unsigned until AVX512, with `vcvtps2udq` (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vcvtps2udq).  For scalar you normally just convert to 64-bit signed (`cvtss2si rax, xmm0`) and take the low 32 bits of that (in EAX), but that's not an option with SIMD.

Without AVX-512, **ideally you can use a signed conversion** (`cvtps2dq`) and get the same result.  i.e. **if your floats are non-negative and <= `INT_MAX`** (`2147483647.0`).

See [How to efficiently perform double/int64 conversions with SSE/AVX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144668/how-to-efficiently-perform-double-int64-conversions-with-sse-avx) for a related double->uint64_t conversion.  The full-range one should be adaptable from double->uint64_t to float->uint32_t if you need it.

Another possibility (for 32-bit float->uint32_t) is just range-shifting to signed in FP, then flipping back in integer.  `INT32_MIN ^ convert(x + INT32_MIN)`.  But that introduces FP rounding for small integers because INT32_MIN is outside the -2<sup>24</sup> .. 2<sup>24</sup> range where a `float` can represent every integer.  e.g. `5` would be rounded to the nearest multiple of 2<sup>8</sup> during conversion.  So that's not usable; you'd need to try straight conversion and range-shifted conversion, and only use the range-shifted conversion if straight conversion gave you `0x80000000`.  (Perhaps using the straight conversion result as a blend control for SSE4 `blendvps`?)

---

For packed conversion of float->int32_t, there is SSE2 `cvtps2dq xmm, xmm/m128` [docs](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvtps2dq).  (`cvttps2dq` converts with truncation toward 0, instead of the current default rounding mode (nearest, if you haven't changed it).)

Any negative float less than -0.5 will convert to integer -1 or lower; as an `uint32_t` that bit-pattern represents a huge number.  Floats outside the -2<sup>31</sup>..2<sup>31</sup>-1 range get converted to `0x80000000`, Intel's "integer indefinite" value.

---

If you didn't find that, only cvtps2pi signed conversion into an MMX register, you need better places to search:

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info - links
- https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ x86 instruction-set list.
- https://www.officedaytime.com/simd512e/simd.html - lists of instructions by category / function
- https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/ - asm instruction mnemonics are listed for intrinsics that only expose the functionality of a single instruction.  And normally you're better off writing C with intrinsics than asm by hand, especially if you don't already know about relatively common / simple instructions like `cvtps2dq` and `cvttps2dq`.
- https://agner.org/optimize/ - his asm optimization guide has a chapter on SIMD with a handy table of different kinds of data-movement instructions.
- [How can I convert an XMM register of single-precision floats to integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861499/how-can-i-convert-an-xmm-register-of-single-precision-floats-to-integers) - a pointer in the right direction, but covering only signed conversion.  I didn't find an exact duplicate.

Comment: You could subtract `2**32` from the float, if the input is larger than `2**31` (one comp+and+sub in addition to the `cvtps2dq`)

Comment: @chtz: What's the advantage to subtracting `2**32` for large floats, instead of `2**31` like I suggested with `INT32_MIN ^ convert(x + INT32_MIN)`?  The top half of the uint32 range is `2**31 .. 2**32 - 1`, so subtracting 2^31 never increases the magnitude of any inputs > 2^31, thus doesn't do more rounding.

Comment: You won't have any rounding problems (since values `>=2**31` will be mapped to values in `[-2**31, 0]`, so you need only one conversion. And subtracting `2**32` automatically gives the correct wrap around behavior as if having done an unsigned conversion (unless the input was larger than `UINT32_MAX`).

Comment: @chtz: Oh I see, integer add of `2**32` is a no-op.  Yeah that's a neat idea.  [edit] my answer if you like, or post your own.  My answer is mainly focused on the point that signed conversion can be used when your numbers are non-negative and not huge; a separate answer might be best for actual working full-range conversion methods.